# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, dynamicobject

When I try to assign a value to the ViewBag I get the following error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'

My code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Success()
{
   ViewBag["SuccessBody"] = TempData["successBody"];
   return View();
}
```

PS: Why I do this you may ask? Because I am redirecting to the Success action and I needed something that persists across redirects. Then, I am assigning the value to ViewBag in order to pass the Value to a 'shared' view.

Comment: But you can just use TempData. It will survive for one redirect.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately shared views do not support the TempData objects.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using to compile this code?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012, upd4.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Have you tried

```
ViewBag.SuccessBody = TempData["successBody"];
```

Comment: What's the reason you can't use an indexer?

Comment: DynamicObjects do not expose their children as an array directly. This is just how it was designed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah I see, it's easy to miss. So a `ViewBag` can access them as dynamic properties, while `ViewData` can access them with an indexer?

Comment: Yes, Viewdata is a ViewDataDictionary which implements the interface IDictionary. That is why you can use an indexer on it.

Answer (score 31):

ViewBag is a dynamic wrapper for ViewData, so these two statements are the same:

```
ViewBag.SuccessBody = TempData["successBody"];
ViewData["SuccessBody"] = TempData["successBody"];
```

Answer (score 8):

`ViewBag` and `ViewData` seem kind of interchangable, but there are different rules as to how you access the data inside of them.  Your issue pops up when you try to index into a `ViewBag`, which doesn't work.

For `ViewBag`, you dereference the items with a dot, like this.

`ViewBag.MyItem`

However, with `ViewData`, you access the items by indexing the appropriate key from the key value dictionary like this.

`ViewData["MyItem"]`